# Relationships & Dating is launching

Tags: discussion, migration

[Relationships & Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating) has reached 100% commitment and will be launching private beta soon.  We [discussed](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/490/644) this previously somewhat, but now that the launch is imminent, I thought it would be a good time to clarify how we should handle overlapping questions:  those relationship problems that are also about parents.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

As the moderator of two sites with a pretty large overlap (Space Exploration and Astronomy), I thought I'd leave you some advice that was given to me.

Beofett has already touched on this, but I figure any extra advice is welcome:

It is ok if some posts that come on Parenting would also be on topic on Relationships & Dating and vice versa. What matters is whether or not it is on topic **here**. Generally, if it is on topic here, **don't migrate**. If the question asked about the relationship between two adults happens to be very pertinent to parenting, then it should stay here.

Comment: Examples: "How will me dating affect my children" (and related), "My child is x-years old and wants to start dating..." (questions about how to handle this, make sure it's safe, etc), and others are all fine to stay here.  "I'm starting to date a single parent..." would depend on the context of the question.

Comment: @Doc Relationships and Dating is closing so this is no longer relevant, but thanks for the comment!

Comment: Really?  It's only been what, 20 days? Awfully quick turnaround.

Comment: @Doc It just sort of failed to pan out, unfortunately. It was already a stretch for the Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 7):

One thing to consider is sharing chat feeds.

By way of example, scifi.se has a chat feed set up to bring in new questions posted on movies.se that use the tags [science-fiction](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction), [fantasy](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy), or [star-wars](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars).  I think we should work with the moderators of the new site to coordinate a similar setup.

Perhaps they would be interested in seeing our [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) questions as they get posted (incidentally, we should be more diligent in using that tag).  Similarly, if they wind up having tags that are directly relevant to us, we can bring them in to our feed.

As for what questions belong where... *it's okay to have topics overlap between two SE sites.*.

I see no problem in having questions about relationships be potentially on topic for either site.

Clearly, for us, the relationship has to somehow relate to a parent/guardian:child relationship, but those could conceivably be okay in **either** site.

Migration should only occur if a question is off-topic on the site it is posted, but on-topic for the other site (and the other site has indicated that it will be welcome), or if it is on-topic for both sites, and the OP *specifically requests a migration*.  Otherwise, it should stay where it was originally posted.

Comment: That last paragraph should be the accepted policy for this site!

Comment: As an FYI, from an active SciFi.SE user's POV, the sharing that Befoett mentioned in the second paragraph is very very helpful and I wholeheartedly endorse this idea.

Comment: @Torben that actually is the accepted Stack Exchange policy across all sites with overlaps. The only thing I would change is that in the second clause, where it's on topic for both and the OP requests migration, that I would add a third clause that the target community (represented by that site's moderators in TL) agree to it coming over.

Comment: @corsiKa good point.  I didn't mention that because I assumed it to be implicit in the migration policy: **nothing** should be migrated before checking to ensure it will be welcome on the new site.  However, that may not be common knowledge.

Comment: We  summarize that policy in a new meta post.

Answer (score 4):

One aspect that seems simple enough is this:

If the topic involves *parenting* then it's on-topic here, and if it just happens to involve *parents* then it would be on-topic there.

Put another way, does the topic directly concern the children (parenting), or just the adults (relationships)?

Comment: I like the distinction between *parents* and *parenting*. When you think about it, they're kidn of like hardware and software. That being said, it is hard to discuss parenting without the impact on the children. It will require judicious analysis of each individual question to determine which site it belongs on.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Torben and as a moderator for parenting, I'll probably go over and join the relationships one too - I imagine there will be frequent occurrences when we'll want to migrate questions back and forth between the two or times when it might be helpful to refer someone here with a parenting question that also relates to relationships to an answer or question there within an answer focused on just the parenting aspects.  The two sites will probably wind up somewhat tied together so it'll be good to have a relationship with each-other (no pun intended - but chuckle slightly anyway if you wish).

Comment: While you're over there (once it launches), post in their meta and tell their mods (TL?) that we are here, friendly, and happy to handle interesting overlaps. Nip problems in the bud, so to speak.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun, They saw Karl's mention and possted it to their chat room (which they do have already) and I've introduced myself  :-)